# How to Replace Custom Strings to Regex Area

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

I'm building "get all site links" class lib in my application. Function parameters are segments and returning as website url.

My regexs that stored in database like that `blog/([a-z]+)(/[a-z0-9.-]+)?`

I want to replace regexs with my "matched" data (segments).

Segments are string or array, may be both. But prefered using as array

**Example 1:**

Regex : `blog/([a-z]+)(/[a-z0-9.-]+)?`

Segments : `news`, `new-software-released`

Result : `blog/news/new-software-released`

**Example 2:**

Regex : `blog/([a-z]+)(/[a-z0-9.-]+)?`

Segments : `news`

Result : `blog/news`

**Example 3:**

Regex : `user(/[a-z0-9.-]+)?`

Segments : `johndoe`

Result : `user/johndoe`

Tried preg_replace array but i couldnt figure out:

```
function get_url($segments){
    $regex = "blog/([a-z]+)(/[a-z0-9.-]+)?"
    $replacements = explode('|', trim($segments));
    $count = 0;
    return preg_replace('/'.$regex.'/', '$replacements[$count++]', $regex);
}

echo get_url('news|new-software-released');
```

Comment: It seems like you need to replace `|` with `/` in the parameter and _concatenate_ it with `blog/`?

Comment: Why are you using `$regex` as both the regular expression and the subject of the replacement?

Comment: How can you do Example 3, when you have `blog/` hard-coded into your function? It will never return `user/`.

Comment: Unfortunately, i have to. I'm using CodeIgniter and both to be the same.

Comment: This function just for example, I'm getting regexs dynamicly from db

Comment: That makes no sense, the regular expression doesn't match itself. It's looking for only letters after the first `/`, but the regexp contains brackets, parentheses, etc.

Comment: @Barmar So i need to create temp string like `blog/temp/temp` for replacement?

Comment: I guess so. Regular expressions are normally used when you have some original string, and you want to replace something in it. I don't understand what you're doing if there's no original string.

Comment: There is no original string because of site urls are dynamic.

Comment: then what is the regular expression for? Why not just append the segments to `blog/` and `user/`, after replacing the `|` with `/`?

Comment: I'm trying to do get url with requested segments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't really understand what you're doing, but it seems like this would do what you're after:

```
function get_url($prefix, $segments) {
    return $prefix . '/' . implode('/', explode('|', $segments));
}

echo get_url('blog', 'news|new-software-released');
echo get_url('blog', 'news');
echo get_url('user', 'johndoe');
```

Comment: Make sense! But what if regex is like that `another/(regex)-(regex)/view` But it seems very difficult to have such an url like ;)

Comment: Are you trying to use the regexp as a template for how to construct the URL from the segments?

Comment: Absolutely that's what I want! I guess, couldnt tell what I want.

Comment: The problem is that that's backwards. Regexps are for matching strings. There's no general way to take a regexp and an array of results, and get the original string that produced those results.

Answer (score 0):

It work well:

```
<?PHP
function get_url($segments){
    $regex = "blog/([a-z]+)(/[a-z0-9.-]+)?";
    $url = "blog/test";
    $replacements = explode('|', trim($segments));
    if(count($replacements) > 1) $replacements = 'blog/' . $replacements[0] . '/' . $replacements[1];
    else $replacements = 'blog/' . $replacements[0];
    $count = 0;
    return preg_replace('#'.$regex.'#', $replacements, $url);
}

echo get_url('news|new-software-released');
```

Thats return value is `blog/news/new-software-released`